# Youtube IFrame API with backbone

Tags: javascript, iframe, backbone.js, youtube-api

I am trying to use the YoutTube's Iframe API in my backbone application, and I am not sure if my approach is correct.

```
var VideoView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
        initialize: function(){
            var that = this;
            this.currentVideoIndex = 0;

            Events.on("changeVideo", function (target){
                that.changeVideo(target.id);
            });

            _.bindAll(this);

            this.player = new window.YT.Player('player', {
                videoId: this.model.videos[0],
                width: 700,
                height: 400,
                events: {
                    'onStateChange': that.onPlayerStateChange
                },
                playerVars: {
                    autoplay: 1,
                    controls: 1,
                    modestbranding: 1,
                    rel: 0,
                    showInfo: 0
                }
            });
        },
         onPlayerStateChange: function(event) {
                if(event.data == 0 ){
                    this.currentVideoIndex = this.currentVideoIndex + 1;
                    this.player.loadVideoById(this.model.videos[this.currentVideoIndex]);                        
         },

        changeVideo: function(event){
            var newIndex  = this.model.videos.indexOf(event);
            this.currentVideoIndex = newIndex;
            this.player.loadVideoById(event);
        }
    });
```

This is the code I use to create a new YT.Player object. Everything works fine for the first time my view gets initialized and the "changeVideo' method works as expected. However if I go to another page and come back to the page with the Iframe player, the first video starts as expected however when I try to change the video I get an error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'postMessage' of null
```

In both cases my OnPlayerState change method works as expected- the next video starts playing after the current video is over.

Here is a screenshot of the error if that helps:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/zmdo80yux4h7pg8/Screenshot%202013-12-04%2013.13.35.png

You can also see a live website here http://gorlla.herokuapp.com/, if you just click on one of the courses and click go to class after you won't be able to go to the next video and if you open the console you would see the "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'postMessage' of null" message.

Comment: I'd like to help, but `postMessage` isn't in the code you provided here and your site is not currently loading any javascript.

Comment: Am trying out your site but cant figure out how to go to the next video.

Comment: I'm opened http://gorlla.herokuapp.com/ and go to course `Obamacare: Explained`, click on `go to class`, and click on `Youtoons Obamacare` and `Khan Academy`. Everythings is ok. Firefox 27.

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all and unrelated, you're defining 'that' twice.

Secondly, why not try calling .destroy on the player when you leave the page, since (if I understand correctly) it gets re-initialized each time you come back.

I have to say, most of the errors I've seen similar to this one relate to the way Chrome manages iFrame state. The iFrame for example will be null if it isn't attached to the DOM. Not sure how this works on other browsers though. Are you removing the DOM element manually from somewhere else? I had a similar issue and found this page helpful:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube-api-gdata/bThZuUg51qg

To summarize, try doing some clean up before hand and play around with .destroy.